# Swift Instagram API username isn't displayed on label

Tags: ios, swift, api, instagram-api

I just wanna make an iOS app with Instagram API then I can see the user profile.
I just wrote this Code on my Xcode project to make iOS app.

here is the code :--

```
    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.delegate = self
        signInRequest()
    }

    func signInRequest() {
        let getURL = String(format: "%@?client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&response_type=token&scope=%@&DEBUG=True", arguments: [API.INSTAGRAM_AUTHURL,API.INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID,API.INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI,API.INSTAGRAM_SCOPE])
        let request = URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string: getURL)!)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }

    func checkRequestForCallbackURL(request: URLRequest) -> Bool {

        let requestURLString = (request.url?.absoluteString)! as String
        if requestURLString.hasPrefix(API.INSTAGRAM_REDIRECT_URI) {
            let range: Range<String.Index> = requestURLString.range(of: "#access_token=")!
            handleAuth(authToken: requestURLString.substring(from: range.upperBound))
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    func handleAuth(authToken: String) {
        let url = String(format: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=%@", authToken)
        let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData



        let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

        session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if let data = data {
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary
                let strFullName = (json?.value(forKey: "data") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "full_name") as! String


                let secondVC: SecondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondSeg") as! SecondViewController

                secondVC.text = strFullName

                self.present(secondVC
                    , animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }.resume()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebView.NavigationType) -> Bool {
        return checkRequestForCallbackURL(request: request)
    }
}
```

my question is when I run my app and want to see the instagram user username I can't see on my label.

I can't see the user (full_name, username, followers, etc...)

here is secondVC Code.

```
    var text: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        userNameLabel?.text = text
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your viewdidload function is being called before the update of your text variable

Try replacing:

```
var text: String = ""
```

With:

```
var text: String = "" {
    didSet {
        userNameLabel?.text = text
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much. another question.. how can I get the user (Media, Followers, Following etc)?

Comment: I just tried this code : - let followers = (json?.value(forKey: "data") as AnyObject).value(forKey: "followers") as! Int.   but nothing happened

Comment: Could you please show me the json so that I help you? Haven’t worked on instagram api recently